# Function call of an outer function within another function stops function from executing

Tags: javascript

I have these two functions declared in the same `.js` file. The first `httpGet` function is supposed to make requests to a RESTful API using the `GET` method. This function is one that I have used before and I know that it works. The second function titled `basicAccess` receives input from an HTML form.

Everything up until the `var httpreq = httpGet("127.0.0.1:5000")` function call in the `basicAccess` function executes. As soon as it hits this line the script stops evaluating further lines of code.

I don't want to have to clutter the `basicAccess` function with the stuff from the `httpGet` function. Ideally I would also like the regex matching to be in it's own function as well, but when I tried that it also stops the script from executing lines once I try to reference a function outside.

Please let me know if you have any insight to how I am approaching this wrong. Fairly knew to JavaScript and didn't even know how to adequately search for this in the forum.

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function basicAccess (form) {
    start =form.StartDate.value;
    end =form.EndDate.value;
    ethosBoundary = "2015-12-01"; 
    arg = 'false';
    re = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

    if(form.StartDate.value != '' && !form.StartDate.value.match(re)) {
        alert("Invalid date format: " + form.StartDate.value);
        form.StartDate.focus();
        return false;
     }
    var httpreq = httpGet("127.0.0.1:5000");

    if (start > end){
        alert ("Error: " + "The start date: " + start + ", occurs after the end date: " + end);
        return;}
    if ((start < ethosBoundary) && (end < ethosBoundary))
        arg = 'both less';
    if ((start > ethosBoundary) && (end >  ethosBoundary)) 
        arg = 'both greater';
    if ((start < ethosBoundary) && (end > ethosBoundary)) 
        arg = 'start less end greater';

    alert ("you typed: " + arg)
}
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question - why are you making a synchronous call? This can all be done asynchronously, using callbacks

Comment: Look at the browser console. Are there any errors / notices? I could imagine the code terminates if you make a synchronous request to another URI but CORS is not enabled.

Comment: what do you do whith `httpreq` because you don't seem to use it, or sending anything, so why this call : `httpGet("127.0.0.1:5000");` ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day I took out the bits where I actually used it and actually changed the URL in the GET request before submitting it here. Essentially I will use it to fetch data from some databases and create some charts using the Google API. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of advice - when a function's default operation is asynchronous, it's a bad idea to tamper with that unless you know why.

I assume the operation of your code is halting while it waits for a server response, this is a classic side-effect of blocking synchronous operations - you want yours to be [non-blocking](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/10/what-is-a-non-blocking-script/), which is where callbacks come in.

I've implemented your code to use a callback instead of a variable assignment - this allows it to remain asynchronous, as `XMLHttpRequests` were intended:

```
function httpGet(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }   
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function basicAccess (form) {
    var start = form.StartDate.value;
    var end = form.EndDate.value;
    var ethosBoundary = "2015-12-01"; 
    var arg = 'false';

    if (!check(form)) return false;

    httpGet("127.0.0.1:5000", function(httpreq){
        if (start > end){
            alert ("Error: " + "The start date: " + start + ", occurs after the end date: " + end);
            return;
        }
        if ((start < ethosBoundary) && (end < ethosBoundary))
            arg = 'both less';
        if ((start > ethosBoundary) && (end >  ethosBoundary)) 
            arg = 'both greater';
        if ((start < ethosBoundary) && (end > ethosBoundary)) 
            arg = 'start less end greater';

        alert ("you typed: " + arg)
    });
}

function check (form) {        
    var start = form.StartDate.value;
    var end = form.EndDate.value;
    var re = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

    if(start != '' && !start.match(re)) {
        alert("Invalid date format: " + start);
        form.StartDate.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'd be happy to explain if you have any other questions.

Comment: Alright, thanks! However, still didn't seem to fix the issue the alert at the end of the httpGet function doesn't appear when I submit the form and I am not sure why?

Comment: @StevenLayne I'm afraid I won't be able to diagnose the issue without a real world example of the problem - try inserting `console.log()` debugging  lines at key points in the program to see where it halts (i've also seperated the regex function like you wanted)

Comment: Thanks! I will keep inspecting.